# Set a variable with multiple IF statements with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set a variable that needs to concatenate certain pieces of string if certain conditions are met.
I have tried:

```
var A; 
  if (B == "Waiting for access") {"Aria POS\n"}
  if (C == "Waiting for access") {"CBS\n"};
```

I have also tried:

```
var A =
   (B === "Waiting for access") ? "Aria POS\n" : "" +
   (C === "Waiting for access") ? "CBS\n" : "" ;
```

but this only returns the 1st string **Aria POS** without the 2nd string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script need variable assignment. In ternary operator, it may help to enclose parentheses for multiple conditions. You could put on different line for readability.

As an example:

```
var A = ""; 
A += (B === "Waiting for access") ? "Aria POS\n" : "";
A += (C === "Waiting for access") ? "CBS\n" : "";
```

Comment: It logs the strings but also ads undefined to it: ``` undefinedAria POS
CBS ```

Comment: Because `A` is undefined at initialization. To fix that, simply initialize `var A = "";`.